# Guaranteed alignment of adress allocated by new expression

Tags: c++, memory, c++17, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am compiling the code with gcc 11.4 with -m32 -std=c++20 on Linux

```
alignof(max_align_t) == 16
__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ == 16
```

What is the guaranteed alignment that I should expect from new expression?
According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/max_align_t:

> Pointers returned by allocation functions such as std::malloc are suitably aligned for any object, which means they are aligned at least as strictly as std::max_align_t.
>
> std::max_align_t is usually synonymous with the largest scalar type, which is long double on most platforms, and its alignment requirement is either 8 or 16.

So I would say that it should be 16 bytes, however I see in gdb/debug logs that adresses returned by new expressions in my application are aligned only to 8 bytes.

According to:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html
I should expect 8 bytes alignment. What is the truth?

If it's ok that new/malloc returns 8 byte aligned adresses and **STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT** == 16 then if you want to allocate memory for 16 bytes aligned entity you can fall into a "hole" in allocation mechanism as 8 bytes alignment is not sufficient but your 16 bytes aligned entity can not trigger operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T)))) from c++17.

Is this simmilar problem to the one described here?
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15795

Example on godbolt (unfortunatelly the issue is not visible here):
https://godbolt.org/z/53db4sYe7

Output of the program from local machine:

> Foo 0
> align_val_t 8
> char 8

Checking adresses with debug logs and gdb.
Googling simmilar issues.

Edit: new statements -> new expressions

Comment: What OS? If Windows, what MinGW distribution (include link)? Can you add a [mcve] (a small program that allocates stuff and prints addresses, that prints non-16-aligned addresses for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global non-placement new expression aligns the object that it creates suitably as its type requires, in C++17 also for over-aligned types. This may not hold true if user overloads of `operator new` are used.

There generally aren't any further requirements on stricter alignment, but some exceptions exist.

An important exception exists for  `std::byte`, `unsigned char` and `char` allocating array-new expressions without specified alignment, which will align the array object so that its address is suitably aligned for any object up to the array's size that doesn't exceed the largest fundamental alignment, i.e. `alignof(max_align_t)`, *and* doesn't have new-extended alignment, i.e. alignment requirement larger than `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`.

Technically any supported alignment may be explicitly specified in a placement-new, e.g. with `new(std::align_val_t{/*alignment here*/}) T(/*...*/)`, however this will cause problems when trying to delete the object again, because the compiler will make the decision to provide alignment details to `operator delete` based on the allocated type. Because allocations for different alignments may use different allocators, this can cause a mismatched allocation/deallocation and UB. So this isn't practically suitable. For array-new forms there is also generally no guarantee that the specified alignment will transfer to the object's alignment.

---

If `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` is larger than what `std::malloc` guarantees, then `operator new(std::size_t)` cannot generally (for large enough size arguments) use `std::malloc` as implementation.

`operator new(std::size_t)` must always guarantee alignment for all objects of size equal to the provided size argument and alignment requirement up to `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` and in the case of `operator new[](std::size_t)` this also applies to all objects of sizes *smaller* than the provided size argument. This holds true even for user overloads and replacements of `operator new`/`operator new[]`. If a user defines (and uses) a `operator new`/`operator new[]` which doesn't guarantee this, then the program has undefined behavior.

The above paragraph also extends to all other `operator new`/`operator new[]` overloads that don't take a `std::align_val_t` argument, except for the reserved placement forms (`operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr)` and `operator new[](std::size_t size, void* ptr)`). With a `std::align_val_t` the overload shall align to the specified argument.

Note however that alignment guarantee of the return value from `operator new`/`operator new[]` is generally not the same as the alignment guarantee for the object created by a new-expression. There are conditions under which the compiler may offset the object in the storage returned by the allocation function and there are conditions under which the compiler can drop or merge allocation function calls to optimize memory usage.

Comment: The character array alignment guarantee is interesting, and useful since such types can be untyped memory used for placement new. For reference, do you know where the standard makes that statement?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I made a slight mistake which is fixed now. It is a combination of https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#stc.dynamic.allocation-3.2 and https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#16.sentence-3 and that is precisely the rationale for this guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the `new` operator guarantees alignment for any type.

According to the C++ Standard, section 5.3.4:

> The address of the newly allocated object shall be a multiple of the
> alignment of the new object's type.

Alignment is an implementation detail, meaning that the behavior is defined by the implementation. In general, for types that are larger than the largest fundamental data type, the alignment will be based on the size of the type.

However, note that there is an additional requirement in C++ that objects of type `T` should be properly aligned if they are declared at block scope (for local variables) or at namespace scope (for global variables).

So, while `new` does guarantee proper alignment for any type, the overall system needs to be configured to meet this requirement. For example, in the case of Windows, the `new` operator can handle alignments up to 8 bytes, which covers the needs of all primitive types.

It is worth noting that, while the C++ Standard guarantees the alignment of objects, the C Standard does not provide this level of alignment guarantees.